# EF Core 2.0 IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementation issues

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

Using EF Core 2.0 i am trying to implement IDesignTimeDbContextFactory to read connection string from the appsettings.json file. I am getting following error on call to SetBasePath

**ConfigurationBuilder does not contain a definition of SetBasePath( )**

```
    public class DbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<TestDbContext>
{
    public TestDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestDbContext>();

        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new TestDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

Second Question : Using this approach is it necessary to use dotnet CLI, will this method be called if i am just running my migration commands using "Package Manager Console" ?

Answer (score 2):

The `SetBasePath()` method is an extension method in FileExtensions.

You can get it by adding the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions` package. I see you have `AddJsonFile()` also, so you might want to use `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` instead since it depends on `FileExtensions` (i.e you'll get both).

On the 2nd question, you don't *need* the `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<>`, but without if you'll need to set the connection string in another place that is accessible during design time.  Another example is to set it in the constructor of your `DbContext`, but that has various design problems like if you want to run a test vs production instance.

If you don't have a factory the `DbContext` is created using a public parameterless constructor.